# jQuery filedrop with multiple drop areas

Tags: jquery, html, file-upload

I'm trying to build a page with multiple drop areas for uploading files. Each area will have specific parameters to accept/upload different kinds of images. I've used jQuery [filedrop](https://github.com/weixiyen/jquery-filedrop).

All goes well with an unique drop zone, but with multiple areas, only the last one works.
You can see an [example here](http://areatest1.latuagenziadiviaggi.it/lab/html5upload/filedrop.html).

I don't know if this is a limit of filedrop or if I'm doing something wrong.

Someone can help me?

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to find a solution to this right now. Did you?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the beginning of a solution to this.

What you can do is create one function for each dropbox

```
$.fn.filedrop = function(options) {
    opts1 = $.extend( {}, default_opts, options );

    this.bind('drop', drop).bind('dragenter', dragEnter).bind('dragover', dragOver).bind('dragleave', dragLeave);
    $(document).bind('drop', docDrop).bind('dragenter', docEnter).bind('dragover', docOver).bind('dragleave', docLeave);
};
```

create a var `opts1` for the first drop box then a var `opts2` for the second dropbox and so on... and replace in each function `$.fn.filedrop` the var `opts` by `opts1` `opts2` so you have a function`$.fn.filedrop1`for the first drop box then a`$.fn.filedrop2` for the second and so on. In each function you bind the drop function to a `drop1` `drop2` functions `this.bind('drop', drop2)` for each and you create as many drop functions as you have dropboxes. In each drop function you add the first line so on each drop it will update the  options according to the dropbox

```
function drop2(e) {
    opts = opts2;
    opts.drop(e);
    files = e.dataTransfer.files;
    if (files === null || files === undefined) {
        opts.error(errors[0]);
        return false;
    }

    files_count = files.length;
    upload();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

of course you bind each filedrop function according to each dropbox `dropbox2.filedrop2({...`

Comment: I've tried this, but without good results. I've tried with another jquery plugin, uploadify 5, with the same problem. I'm thinking this isa browser limit. I've builded the same application without darg and drop (with uploadify 5) and it works.